# Kendo Angular Scheduler: How to add breaks (like coffee, lunch)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have `kendo-ui` scheduler component for `angular`. I have events and resources like shown in attached image.

What I am looking for is to add breaks/pauses to scheduler.

**For example:**

car service event starts from 08:30 to 10:00. I want to add/show 15 minutes break from 9:15 to 9:30

kendo binds events array and one event object includes `id`, `title`, `start`, `end`, `resourceId`

[image]

**Result I am looking for:**
[image]

Any help how we can add breaks to kendo scheduler for angular would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The component will render the events as your data has them represented. If you want to stop the event midway through for some amount of time and then pick it back up, then you will need to massage the data to show two separate events.

Assuming your data is coming in as a single record with a "break" property like this:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Car Service",
    "start": "2020/06/24 08:30:00AM",
    "end": "2020/06/24 09:15:00AM",
    "break": {
      "start": "2020/06/24 09:15:00AM",
      "end": "2020/06/24 09:30:00AM"
    }
  }
]
```

Then you will need to map the data. For example:

```typescript
this.myservice.getEvents()
  .pipe(map((events) => {
    const mappedEvents = [];
    events.forEach(event => {
      if (!event.break) {
          mappedEvents.push(event);
          return;
      }
      event.end = event.break.start;
      mappedEvents.push(event);

      const eventPart2 = event;
      eventPart2.start = event.break.end;
      mappedEvents.push(eventPart2);
    });
    return mappedEvents;
  }))
  .subscribe((events) => this.events = events);
```

Comment: is there any other way to bind breaks to scheduler ? like Instead of adding break events, can I add breaks directly to scheduler

Comment: @Yousaf - no, not as far as I'm aware. You would need to massage the data to fit in your breaks.